# Overriding background:url with background-color in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to override background: url with background-color, but for some reason the background: url is still in front. What should I do instead?

```css
body {
  background: url("https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg");
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to override the `background` property, override it using the `background` property rather than `background-color`:

```css
body {
  background: url("https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg");
  background: green; /* This will override the previous property */
}
```

Alternatively, could add also just add `background-image: none` in addition to `background-color: green`:

```css
body {
  background: url("https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg");
  background-color: green;  
  background-image: none;
}
```